# transition functions of a vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

why are the transition functions  in the definition of a vector bundle $P:E \rightarrow M$ termed as transition functions? they are  $g_{\alpha \beta}:U_{\alpha} \cap U_\beta \rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ and defined as $\phi_{\beta} \circ \phi_{\alpha}^{-1} : (U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}) \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow (U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}) \times \mathbb{R}^n$ where $(U_{\alpha}, \phi_{\alpha})$ are charts of $M$.I am not getting how transition functions  perform change from one chart of $M$  to another?Please explain with an example if possible

Answer (score 2):

Over $U_\alpha$ and $U_\beta$, you have two different trivializations. When you change coordinates from one trivialization to the other, you have to apply a change-of-basis map *to each fiber*. The change of coordinate map on the fiber over $x$ is the linear map $g_{\alpha\beta}(x)$.

If this is too general, think of a change-of-coordinates for an ordinary manifold. Its differential is a family of linear change-of-basis maps, one on each tangent space. The $g_{\alpha\beta}$ are defined in the same spirit.

Answer (score 2):

I just learned about vector bundles earlier this year, so perhaps my answer is a bit hand-wavey, but the intuition I get out of it is that the transition maps provide instructions on how to glue the patches $U_\alpha\times\Bbb{R}^n$ and $U_\beta\times\Bbb{R}^n$ together, and these instructions naturally belong to $GL_n(\Bbb{R})$. The image of $x\in U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$ under $g_{\alpha\beta}$ tells you how to identify $\phi_\alpha^{-1}(\pi^{-1}(x))\cong \Bbb{R}^n$ with $\phi_\beta^{-1}(\pi^{-1}(x))\cong \Bbb{R}^n$.

Take the Möbius strip for example (as an $\Bbb{R}$-bundle over $\Bbb{S}^1$). Cover it with three open sets $U_1$, $U_2$, $U_3$ in (sorry for saying this) the most obvious way. On $U_1\cap U_2$ and $U_2\cap U_3$, make your transition function the constant map $x\mapsto$id$_{\Bbb{R}}$, and on $U_3\cap U_1$, the constant map $x\mapsto-$id$_{\Bbb{R}}$. This accounts for the half-twist in the Möbius strip.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer this question pointwise, i.e. fix $p\in U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\subset \mathcal{M}$. Fix also the easy example of the **tangent (vector) bundle**, i.e. $P:T\mathcal{M}\rightarrow\mathcal{M}$.
Recall that a vector $V\in T_p \mathcal{M}$ at $p$ can be expressed in two different frames like $$V=V^\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}|_p=\bar{V}^\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial y^\mu}|_p\quad (\mu=1,..,n\quad\text{summed}).$$
Note the crucial point that $V$ and $(V^\mu)_{\mu=1,..n}$ and $(\bar{V}^\mu)_{\mu=1,..n}$ all contain the same information about the vector $V$. I.e. we can define bijections
$$\phi_{\alpha,p}^{-1}: T_p\mathcal{M}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n, V\mapsto (V^\mu)_{\mu=1,..n}\\
\phi_{\beta,p}^{-1}: T_p\mathcal{M}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n, V\mapsto (\bar{V}^\mu)_{\mu=1,..n}$$
which (modulo checking diff'ability) are two local trivializations at the fixed point $p$. In the $T\mathcal{M}$ context, they bare the better known name *coordinate functions*. Coloquially speaking, but rather importantly, they can only tell you something about your geometric structure if you remember **which frame they make sense in**, namely $\phi_{\alpha,p}^{-1}$ in $x^\mu$ and $\phi_{\beta,p}^{-1}$ in $y^\mu$. (I'm being sloppy about notation of the frames here.)
You know how to go from here, I'm convinced: Commutatively completing the triangle
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
T_p\mathcal{M} @>\phi_{\alpha,p}^{-1}>> \mathbb{R}^n\ni(V^1,..V^n)\\
@V \phi_{\beta,p}^{-1} VV\\
\mathbb{R}^n@.\ni(\bar{V}^1,..\bar{V}^n)
\end{CD}
gives you two (hence equal) maps:

1. the map that translates $V$'s coordinates between frames $x^\mu$ and $y^\mu$
2. $g_{\alpha\beta,p}:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$. (by your definition - modulo some $\cdot^{-1}$)

Answer (score 0):

I am still learning about vector bundles, so if there is something incomplete, please say! I will give you the example of the most important vector bundle, the tangent bundle!

Let $M$ be a manifold of dimension $n$ and consider an atlas $\{(U_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)\}$ where the coordinate maps read $\varphi_\alpha : U_\alpha \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. We know that $TM$ is itself a vector bundle, namely of rank $n$ where we can consider the traivializing open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ together with the trivializations $\{\phi_\alpha\}$ given by $$\phi_\alpha : \pi^{-1}(U_\alpha) \rightarrow U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^n,$$where $\pi : TM \rightarrow M$ is the usual projection and $\phi_\alpha(p,v) = (p,d_{\varphi_\alpha}(v))$. Now, it is important to observe that $$d_p\varphi_{\alpha} : T_pM \rightarrow T_{\varphi_\alpha(p)}\mathbb{R}^n \cong \mathbb{R}^n,$$and (by linearity after fixing $p$), is defined as $$d_p\varphi_\alpha(v) = (v_1,\dots,v_n),$$if $v = \sum_{i=1}^nv_1\partial_{x^i}$.

Now, the transition functions, also known as cocycles are given by $g_{\alpha \beta} : U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ where $$g_{\alpha \beta}(p) = \phi_\alpha^p \circ (\phi_\beta^p)^{-1} : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n.$$Going back to the trivializing functions of the tangent bundle we notice that fixing $p$ we get a linear isomorphism (since it is a vector bundle) $$\phi_\alpha^p : T_pM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n,$$which is given by $\phi_\alpha^p(v) = d_p\varphi_\alpha(v)$ defined previously. But then, for any $p \in U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$ we have $$g_{\alpha \beta}(p) = \phi_\alpha^p \circ (\phi_\beta^p)^{-1} = d_{\varphi_\beta^{-1}}\varphi_\alpha \circ d_p{\varphi_\beta^{-1}} = d_p(\varphi_\alpha \circ \varphi_\beta^{-1}),$$which is indeed a map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself. This shows that the transition functions for $TM$ are given by the Jacobian of the transition functions of our manifold.